# Is it possible to set groupId in Spring Boot Stream Kafka at startup or compile-time?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I just started using Spring Boot Stream with Kafka.

I created a producer and a consumer. What I need is to have two identical consumer (pratically two microservices) but with different groupId, so both of them will read the topic and get the same message.

Now I have the groupId in the spring boot application project under resources in properties.yml file, is it possible to set this value at compile time as a parameter or better at startup?

**properties.yml**

```
server:
    port: 8087
eureka:
    client:
        serviceUrl:
            defaultZone: http://IP:8761/eureka
spring:
    application:
        name: employee-producer
    cloud:
        stream:
            kafka:
                binder:
                    brokers: IP:9092
                bindings:
                    greetings-in:
                        destination: greetings
                        contentType: application/json
                    greetings-out:
                        destination: greetings
                        contentType: application/json
    kafka:
                           consumer:
                             group-id: 500
                             client-id: 99
```

Something this:
[image: kafka consumers]

Comment: so in direct manner, you want to read same message by two diff consumers  of diff group @user

Comment: yes, both listening the same topic, however, this is just the use case I'm applying in this use case, but that's not the final purpose

Comment: so if you have one consumer in `group1` which is now consuming messages from topic and you want to add second one of different group `group2`, so while adding you can just set offset to earliest it starts consuming from beginning, so you can add it whenever you want before the retention of data @user

Comment: I don't need the consumer to start from the begin, it can consume from when it starts

Comment: yes it is possible, one topic with two consumers different group id @user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to requirement you need two consumers of different group (which is group.id) on same topic so that every message can be consumed by both consumers

According to documentation **group.id**

> A unique string that identifies the consumer group this consumer belongs to. This property is required if the consumer uses either the group management functionality by using subscribe(topic) or the Kafka-based offset management strategy.

group.id is need to be set at the time initialization of kafkaconsumerfactory

```
 props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
```

Whenever new group consumer with qnique group.id is added to topic it will consume the latest messages because by default **auto.offset.reset** is **latest**

For Example:

1. first send 5 messages to kafka
2. now add new consumer (it won't consume those messages because default offset is latest)

To make it consume those messages offset should be specified to **earliest**